# Keep track of two loops at the same time

Tags: python, for-loop, break

I want to simulate a race between a rabbit and a fox.
Say that I have two lists with different length: a = [1,2,3,4,5,"rabbit", 7,8] and b = [1,2,3,4, "fox",5]. When I loop over list b and fox "breaks" before rabbit - then the fox wins the race.

Example:

```
for x in a:
    if x == "rabbit"
        break

for y in b:
    if x == "fox"
        break
```

Function: Fox won the race!

Is this possible?

Comment: you need to use the `itertools` module

Comment: If you want to do it synchronously, well you cannot have two loops executing in the same time! But if it is just the same iteration, well see the answer bellow.

Comment: Use `zip(a, b)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```py
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    if x == "rabbit":
        rep = "rabbit"
        break
    if y == "fox":
        rep = "fox"
        break
print("{} has won!".format(rep))
```

Is that what you were hopping for?

Comment: Thank you sir. Exactly what I was wondering.

Comment: how does this handle ties? (IOW, you might want to `break` outside of the two `if` statements you already have

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one line:

```
'rabbit' if min([index for index, x in enumerate(a) if x == 'rabbit']) < min([index for index, x in enumerate(b) if x == 'fox']) else 'fox'
```

But @HenriChab's answer is much more readable IMO.